# Programmatically Automating Getting the Correct COM Port, based on the Serial Device, through C#

Tags: .net, serial-port, c#-2.0

I am trying to set up my program to Automatically detect which COM Port is connected to my device, to that end, this is what i have done so far:

I get the COM Ports using

```
string[] comPorts = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
```

Once i have the available COM Ports for my pc, I create a SerialPort instance inside a foreach loop to open and then to send a string command through each available COM Port.  With my Device attached to one of those COM Ports it will respond back with another string command, which i catch through the SerialPort.DataReceived event.

```
foreach(string port in comPorts)
{
    SerialPort sp = new SerialPort(port, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    sp.Handshake = Handshake.None;

    sp.Open();
    sp.Write("<ID01>\r\n"); // this command wakes up the device.  The device then sends back the string "<ID01>S" in which 'S' is the code for Success.
}
```

This works good, I get back the success string just fine.  The reason for all this is that i want the Program to automatically recognize which com port the device is set up on or not setup on.  The problem is that by the time the DataReceived event has returned the Success string the program has already gone past the point where it will do me any good because the Main thread that the program is running on seems to have already progressed on ahead.  I thought maybe i could just pause the main thread by doing Thread.Sleep(10000); but it just seemed like it paused the SerialPort with it.  The SerialPort.DataReceived event still passed back my data after the main thread had already gone by.

so my question is:  Is there any way to pause the main thread to allow the DataReceived information to pass back so that i can process code based on whether or not the device was attached to that specific COM Port?

If not then does anyone have any suggestions how i might be able to accomplish this?

roadmaster

Comment: There's no point in using the DataReceived event until *after* you figured out which port is the one you want.  So set the ReceiveTimeout and call ReadLine().  Beware that what you are doing is pretty dangerous, you might actually be talking to a motor controller.  Do favor the DsrHolding signal first and only do this in in Options screen.

Comment: ReadLine() will wait for a newline character to be received or throw an exception id ReceiveTimeout has elapsed without a newline. Roadmaster indicated that response would be "<ID01>S", if we could guarantee that the response would always be: "<ID01>S\r\n" then he could use ReadLine.

Comment: That was my mistake the Response does indeed include "\r\n" I simply stripped them out.  Generally every response back should include it.  I used your example Tremmors and what I ended up doing was sending the refresh command, Thread.Sleep, then the actual command I wanted to send, then the Thread.Sleep again and it seems to be working well so far.  Im no longer using the DataReceieved Event, I am using your sp.ReadExisting() method, would sp.ReadLine be a better alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using an asynchronous read method, where you really need a synchronous one.

This does approximately the same thing, but all on a single thread:

```
foreach(SerialPort port in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
{
    SerialPort sp = new SerialPort(port, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    sp.Handshake = Handshake.None;

    sp.Open();
    sp.Write("<ID01>\r\n");

    Thread.Sleep(250);  // give it some time to respond

    string response = sp.ReadExisting();
    if(response == "<ID01>S")
    {
        found = true;
        // do something useful
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you that appears to be exactly what I needed.  I believe I need to read up some on the differences between Asynchronous and Synchronous reading.  roadmaster

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` above should read

```
foreach (String port in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the `foreach` function

```
foreach(string port in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
```

would do.